# How can I use ua-parser in my application?

Tags: java, user-agent

How can i use "ua-parser" in my web application?. I can't find any jar archive in git hub repository https://github.com/tobie/ua-parser. I searched google but I can't find any websites for ua-parser. 
Where can i download ua-parser for jar archive?.
Is there any website for ua-parser?
Is anybody using ua-parser?. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Clone the repository and run mvn package from the java folder.
This is explained in details [here](https://github.com/tobie/ua-parser/tree/master/java) 
You'll end up with a jar (actually a bunch of jar if you count the dependencies)